# Cartoon about people on a space mission investigating a zombie virus

Tags: story-identification, cartoon, apocalypse, virus

It's a cartoon about a couple of people on a mission in outer space,I think they were investigating the breakout of a deadly virus that turns dead people into violent zombies. And I can remember they were on a space ship I think it was abandoned. The main character is a girl and she survived till the end where she was able to send a message, I think she died after that. Also there is a lot of blood and gore in the cartoon.

Comment: Can you give us an idea of when this might have come out and when you saw it? Anything specific about the characters or events?

Answer (score 5):

This is possibly the 2008 animated film [Dead Space: Downfall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_Space:_Downfall), although there are a couple of differences.

[image]

> a couple of people on a mission in outer space

It's actually a ship full of people, so not quite the same there.

> they were investigating the breakout of a deadly virus that turns dead people into violent zombies

The original mission of the ship to obtain an alien artifact and return it to Earth. It transpires that the artifact causes people to mutate into violent monsters.

> they were on a space ship I think it was abandoned

The ship isn't abandoned but at the start of the story they investigate a colony near the artifact where everyone has died.

> The main character is a girl

The main protagonist is the ship's head of security, Alissa Vincent.

[image]

> she survived till the end where she was able to send a message, I think she died after that

Alissa survives to the end of the film, records a message describing what has happened to the crew and then opens an airlock, killing herself and some of the creatures.

> Also there is a lot of blood and gore in the cartoon.

It's pretty gory. In the UK it was [released with the "18" certificate](https://bbfc.co.uk/releases/dead-space-downfall-2008) due to "strong bloody violence and gore".